# Is this Metonymy? - using 'it' or 'this' to replace a word

Tags: terminology

What is the correct term to use when referring to the act of replacing a word with 'it' or 'this' e.g instead of 'death is going to happen' 'it is going to happen'.
Also what term would you use for something that refers to something but without being direct e.g. 'current situation' rather than 'dying'
I had wondered if both of the above were types of metonymy but not sure it quite fits that term.
Thanks

Comment: Don't see the metonym here, only a pronoun that substitutes for its antecedent. The throne stands in for the ruler. Saving face stands in for an outer presentation that represents the soul. Bricks stand in for physical presence of a building or business. But when *it* stands in for death, the pronoun was never a part of the whole and does not symbolizes the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is metonymy. The first situation may be called "anaphora". [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anaphora):

> 2: use of a grammatical substitute (such as a pronoun or a pro-verb) to refer to the denotation of a preceding word or group of words

The second situation might be called "euphemism" (as mentioned in another answer) if the purpose was to express an idea in less disagreeable terms. Again, [from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism):

> : the substitution of an agreeable or inoffensive expression for one that may offend or suggest something unpleasant

"Pass away" is a more common euphemism for "die".

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not metonymy. What you are referring to is a euphemishm. This kind of euphemism is sometimes called indirection. For example, "They had sexual intercourse" could be euphemised to "they slept together", or even "they did it".